# Поиск доменного имени в requests при помощи RegEx

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, requests

Как при помощи RegEx вывести доменное имя?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также желательно, чтобы полученный результат выводился без `/` справа и слева.

Сcылки получаются из `requests.get(url).text`, в данном случае ссылка для `requests`- `https://stackoverflow.com/`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


    <html class="html__responsive html__unpinned-leftnav">

    <head>

        <title>Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
        <link rel="image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
        <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
        <meta name="description" content="Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share&#x200B; &#x200B;their programming &#x200B;knowledge, and build their careers."/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta property="og:type" content= "website" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/"/>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Stack Overflow" />
        <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" />
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
        <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
        <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="name" content="Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers" />
        <meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Stack Overflow | The World&#x2019;s Largest Online Community 
for Developers" />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=95d1ce093683"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=50b8afc7d7a9">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=ed592cf7c761">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/Product/product.css?v=6d79cc50f79b">

    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed of recent questions" href="/feeds">





        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/Channels/channels.css?v=a7f9f1d58f12">





    <script>
        StackExchange.init({"locale":"en","serverTime":1609113132,"routeName":"Home/Index","stackAuthUrl":"https://stackauth.com","networkMetaHostname":"meta.stackexchange.com","site":{"name":"Stack Overflow","description":"Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers","isNoticesTabEnabled":true,"enableNewTagCreationWarning":true,"insertSpaceAfterNameTabCompletion":false,"id":1,"childUrl":"https://meta.stackoverflow.com","styleCodeWithHighlightjs":true,"negativeVoteScoreFloor":null,"enableSocialMediaInSharePopup":true,"protocol":"https"},"user":{"fkey":"d47a13fe390690cc7f58ace6a8ae0e3e1b4f077e94cd332a2bdaeabe6c8f5ec8","tid":"52d2ab10-4838-b225-6db6-4b3b7f4c7a82","rep":0,"isAnonymous":true,"isAnonymousNetworkWide":true},"events":{"postType":{"question":1},"postEditionSection":{"title":1,"body":2,"tags":3}},"story":{"minCompleteBodyLength":75,"likedTagsMaxLength":300,"dislikedTagsMaxLength":300},"jobPreferences":{"maxNumDeveloperRoles":2,"maxNumIndustries":4},"svgIconPath":"https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/svg-icons","svgIconHash":"41ca7234d37d"}, {"userProfile":{"openGraphAPIKey":"4a307e43-b625-49bb-af15-ffadf2bda017"},"userMessaging":{"showNewFeatureNotice":true},"tags":{},"subscriptions":{"defaultMaxTrueUpSeats":1000},"snippets":{"renderDomain":"stacksnippets.net","snippetsEnabled":true},"slack":{"sidebarAdDismissCookie":"slack-sidebar-ad","sidebarAdDismissCookieExpirationDays":60.0},"site":{"allowImageUploads":true,"enableImgurHttps":true,"enableUserHovercards":true,"forceHttpsImages":true,"styleCode":true},"intercom":{"appId":"inf0secd","hostBaseUrl":"https://stacksnippets.net"},"paths":{},"monitoring":{"clientTimingsAbsoluteTimeout":30000,"clientTimingsDebounceTimeout":1000},"mentions":{"maxNumUsersInDropdown":50},"markdown":{"enableTables":true},"flags":{"allowRetractingCommentFlags":true,"allowRetractingFlags":true},"comments":{},"accounts":{"currentPasswordRequiredForChangingStackIdPassword":true}});
        StackExchange.using.setCacheBreakers({"js/adops.en.js":"22a9bd59b1e9","js/ask.en.js":"e287ffdc77d4","js/begin-edit-event.en.js":"cb9965ad8784","js/events.en.js":"c6c8889b517b","js/explore-qlist.en.js":"22610455f68f","js/full-anon.en.js":"5161fccab23c","js/full.en.js":"f81a3c6dcad5","js/help.en.js":"b49b1b0c233e","js/highlightjs-loader.en.js":"bb374a2289c0","js/inline-tag-editing.en.js":"64af4cae422c","js/keyboard-shortcuts.en.js":"3131cd802b4b","js/markdown-it-loader.en.js":"ecbf27350e73","js/mobile.en.js":"e8e35effc1e7","js/moderator.en.js":"68a7976fb7ec","js/postCollections-transpiled.en.js":"5e7b256b3872","js/post-validation.en.js":"84327ab5c35a","js/prettify-full.en.js":"705fa0e6be8d","js/question-editor.en.js":"","js/review.en.js":"64b30f5cf8ce","js/review-v2-transpiled.en.js":"6665606b25b3","js/revisions.en.js":"f20f2a79bffd","js/stacks-editor.en.js":"9c3f30b07967","js/tageditor.en.js":"4f30af0fdc59","js/tageditornew.en.js":"37fd6b26bc64","js/tagsuggestions.en.js":"bdfe20bf5338","js/wmd.en.js":"4f962fbc00f6","js/snippet-javascript-codemirror.en.js":"b66c70749b7e"});
        StackExchange.using("gps", function() {
             StackExchange.gps.init(true);
        });
    </script>
    <noscript id="noscript-css"><style>body,.top-bar{margin-top:1.9em}</style></noscript>
    </head>
    <body class="home-page unified-theme">
    <div id="notify-container"></div>
    <div id="custom-header"></div>

<header class="top-bar js-top-bar top-bar__network _fixed">
    <div class="wmx12 mx-auto grid ai-center h100" role="menubar">
        <div class="-main grid--cell">
                <a href="#" class="left-sidebar-toggle p0 ai-center jc-center js-left-sidebar-toggle" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="left-sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><span class="ps-relative"></span></a>
                <div class="topbar-dialog leftnav-dialog js-leftnav-dialog dno">
                    <div class="left-sidebar js-unpinned-left-sidebar" data-can-be="left-sidebar" data-is-here-when="sm md lg"></div>
                </div>
                    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="-logo js-gps-track"
                        data-gps-track="top_nav.click({is_current:true, location:1, destination:8})">
                        <span class="-img _glyph">Stack Overflow</span>
                    </a>



        </div>

            <ol class="list-reset grid gs4" role="presentation">

                    <li class="grid--cell md:d-none">
                        <a href="/company" class="-marketing-link js-gps-track"
                           data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:1, destination:7})"
                            data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;about menu click&quot;,null,null,null]">About</a>
                    </li>

                <li class="grid--cell">
                    <a href="#"
                        class="-marketing-link js-gps-track js-products-menu"
                        aria-controls="products-popover"
                        data-controller="s-popover"
                        data-action="s-popover#toggle"
                        data-s-popover-placement="bottom"
                        data-s-popover-toggle-class="is-selected"
                        data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:1, destination:1})"
                        data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;products menu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                        Products
                    </a>
                </li>

                    <li class="grid--cell md:d-none">
                        <a href="/teams" class="-marketing-link js-gps-track"
                           data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:1, destination:7})"
                            data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;learn more - teams&quot;,null,null,null]">For Teams</a>
                    </li>
            </ol>
            <div class="s-popover ws2 mtn2 p0"
                    id="products-popover"
                    role="menu"
                    aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="s-popover--arrow"></div>
                <ol class="list-reset s-anchors s-anchors__inherit">
                    <li class="m6">
                        <a href="/questions" class="bar-sm p6 d-block h:bg-black-100 js-gps-track"
                           data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:1, destination:2})"
                           data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;public qa submenu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                            <span class="fs-body1 d-block">Stack Overflow</span>
                            <span class="fs-caption d-block fc-light">Public questions &amp; answers</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="m6">
                        <a href="/teams" class="bar-sm p6 d-block h:bg-black-100 js-gps-track"
                           data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:1, destination:3})"
                           data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;teams submenu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                            <span class="fs-body1 d-block">Stack Overflow for Teams</span>
                            <span class="fs-caption d-block fc-light">Where developers &amp; technologists share private knowledge with coworkers</span>        
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="m6">
                        <a href="/jobs?so_source=ProductsMenu&so_medium=StackOverflow" class="bar-sm p6 d-block h:bg-black-100 js-gps-track"
                            data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:1, destination:9})"
                            data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;jobs submenu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                            <span class="fs-body1 d-block">Jobs</span>
                            <span class="fs-caption d-block fc-light">Programming &amp; related technical career opportunities</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="m6">
                        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/talent" class="bar-sm p6 d-block h:bg-black-100 js-gps-track"
                           data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:1, destination:5})"
                           data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;talent submenu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                            <span class="fs-body1 d-block">Talent</span>
                            <span class="fs-caption d-block fc-light">Recruit tech talent &amp; build your employer brand</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="m6">
                        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/advertising" class="bar-sm p6 d-block h:bg-black-100 js-gps-track"
                           data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:1, destination:6})"
                           data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;advertising submenu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                            <span class="fs-body1 d-block">Advertising</span>
                            <span class="fs-caption d-block fc-light">Reach developers &amp; technologists worldwide</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="bg-black-025 bt bc-black-075 py6 px6 bbr-sm">
                        <a href="/company" class="fc-light d-block py6 px6 h:fc-black-800 js-gps-track"
                            data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:1, destination:7})"
                            data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;about submenu click&quot;,null,null,null]">About the company</a>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>

            <form id="search" role="search" action=/search class="grid--cell fl-grow1 searchbar px12 js-searchbar " autocomplete="off">
                    <div class="ps-relative">
                        <input name="q"
                               type="text"
                               placeholder="Search&#x2026;"
                               value=""
                               autocomplete="off"
                               maxlength="240"
                               class="s-input s-input__search js-search-field "
                               aria-label="Search"
                               aria-controls="top-search"
                               data-controller="s-popover"
                               data-action="focus->s-popover#show"
                               data-s-popover-placement="bottom-start"/>
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="s-input-icon s-input-icon__search svg-icon iconSearch" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M18 16.5l-5.14-5.18h-.35a7 7 0 10-1.19 1.19v.35L16.5 18l1.5-1.5zM12 7A5 5 0 112 7a5 5 0 0110 0z"/></svg>
                        <div class="s-popover p0 wmx100 wmn4 sm:wmn-initial js-top-search-popover s-popover--arrow__tl" id="top-search" role="menu">
    <div class="js-spinner p24 grid ai-center jc-center d-none">
        <div class="s-spinner s-spinner__sm fc-orange-400">
            <div class="v-visible-sr">Loading&#x2026;</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <span class="v-visible-sr js-screen-reader-info"></span>
    <div class="js-ac-results overflow-y-auto hmx3 d-none"></div>

    <div class="js-search-hints" aria-describedby="Tips for searching"></div>
</div>
                    </div>
            </form>



<ol class="overflow-x-auto ml-auto -secondary grid ai-center list-reset h100 user-logged-out" role="presentation">
        <li class="-item searchbar-trigger"><a href="#" class="-link js-searchbar-trigger" role="button" aria-label="Search" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="search" title="Click to show search"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconSearch" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M18 16.5l-5.14-5.18h-.35a7 7 0 10-1.19 1.19v.35L16.5 18l1.5-1.5zM12 7A5 5 0 112 7a5 5 0 0110 0z"/></svg></a></li>

            <li class="-ctas">
                            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f" class="login-link s-btn s-btn__filled py8 js-gps-track" rel="nofollow"
                               data-gps-track="login.click" data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;login button click&qu
```

Код:

```
import re, requests 

input_url = input("Enter url: ")

response = requests.get(input_url)

result = re.findall(r'regex here', response.text)
print(result)
```

При существующем regex - `result = re.findall(r'/[A-Za-z.]+/', response.text)`, выводится следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И нужно чтобы выводилось все то же самое, но желательно исключительно ссылки, т.е. те, где есть `.com`, `.net`, итд, а не directory, product, т е конкретно доменное имя, и нужно что бы выводилось без слешей слева и справа, т.е. после выполнения regex нужно не `/cdn.sstatic.net/`, а `cdn.sstatic.net`.

Просьба при недочете в вопросе озвучивать что нужно добавить или исправить.

Comment: Советую воспользоваться [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: проблема в том, что мне нужно конкретно regex

Comment: что мне добавить в вопрос что бы не ставили минус?

Comment: По-моему отлично оформленный вопрос +1 ;)

Comment: Почему задачу надо решить именно регулярками? Если задачу можно решить без регулярных выражений, то лучше это сделать именно так. Вопрос, возможно, минусуют, потому что Вы не приложили своих попыток.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов потому что задача именно в том что бы решить это с помощью регулярок

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27755/10941639.

Comment: там регулярка для всей ссылки, а мне нужно **только** доменное имя

Comment: Подсказка: нужно взять то, что находится между ``://`` и первым ``/``

Comment: @Эникейщик, да, именно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = re.findall( r"\"(?:http[s]?://)([^:/\s\"]+)/?[^\"]*\"", response.text)
```

результат (только уникальные адреса):

```
In [430]: set(res)
Out[430]: 
{'academia.stackexchange.com',
 'ajax.googleapis.com',
 'android.stackexchange.com',
 'anime.stackexchange.com',
 'api.stackexchange.com',
 'apple.stackexchange.com',
 'arduino.stackexchange.com',
 'askubuntu.com',
 'bicycles.stackexchange.com',
 'biology.stackexchange.com',
 'bitcoin.stackexchange.com',
 'blender.stackexchange.com',
 'boardgames.stackexchange.com',
 'bricks.stackexchange.com',
 'cdn.sstatic.net',
 'chat.stackoverflow.com',
 'chemistry.stackexchange.com',
 'chess.stackexchange.com',
 'chinese.stackexchange.com',
 'christianity.stackexchange.com',
 'codegolf.stackexchange.com',
 'codereview.stackexchange.com',
 'cooking.stackexchange.com',
 'crypto.stackexchange.com',
 'cs.stackexchange.com',
 'cstheory.stackexchange.com',
 'data.stackexchange.com',
 'datascience.stackexchange.com',
 'dba.stackexchange.com',
 'diy.stackexchange.com',
 'drupal.stackexchange.com',
 'dsp.stackexchange.com',
 'electronics.stackexchange.com',
 'ell.stackexchange.com',
 'emacs.stackexchange.com',
 'english.stackexchange.com',
 'es.stackoverflow.com',
 'ethereum.stackexchange.com',
 'expressionengine.stackexchange.com',
 'fitness.stackexchange.com',
 'french.stackexchange.com',
 'gamedev.stackexchange.com',
 'gaming.stackexchange.com',
 'gardening.stackexchange.com',
 'german.stackexchange.com',
 'gis.stackexchange.com',
 'graphicdesign.stackexchange.com',
 'hermeneutics.stackexchange.com',
 'history.stackexchange.com',
 'homebrew.stackexchange.com',
 'insights.stackoverflow.com',
 'islam.stackexchange.com',
 'japanese.stackexchange.com',
 'judaism.stackexchange.com',
 'law.stackexchange.com',
 'linguistics.stackexchange.com',
 'linkedin.com',
 'magento.stackexchange.com',
 'martialarts.stackexchange.com',
 'math.stackexchange.com',
 'mathematica.stackexchange.com',
 'mathoverflow.net',
 'mechanics.stackexchange.com',
 'meta.stackexchange.com',
 'meta.stackoverflow.com',
 'money.stackexchange.com',
 'movies.stackexchange.com',
 'music.stackexchange.com',
 'networkengineering.stackexchange.com',
 'outdoors.stackexchange.com',
 'parenting.stackexchange.com',
 'philosophy.stackexchange.com',
 'photo.stackexchange.com',
 'physics.stackexchange.com',
 'pixel.quantserve.com',
 'poker.stackexchange.com',
 'psychology.stackexchange.com',
 'pt.stackoverflow.com',
 'puzzling.stackexchange.com',
 'raspberrypi.stackexchange.com',
 'rpg.stackexchange.com',
 'ru.stackoverflow.com',
 'rus.stackexchange.com',
 'russian.stackexchange.com',
 'salesforce.stackexchange.com',
 'scicomp.stackexchange.com',
 'scifi.stackexchange.com',
 'security.stackexchange.com',
 'serverfault.com',
 'sharepoint.stackexchange.com',
 'skeptics.stackexchange.com',
 'softwareengineering.stackexchange.com',
 'softwarerecs.stackexchange.com',
 'sound.stackexchange.com',
 'spanish.stackexchange.com',
 'sports.stackexchange.com',
 'sqa.stackexchange.com',
 'stackapps.com',
 'stackauth.com',
 'stackexchange.com',
 'stackoverflow.blog',
 'stackoverflow.blog?blb=1',
 'stackoverflow.com',
 'stackoverflowbusiness.com',
 'stacksnippets.net',
 'stats.stackexchange.com',
 'superuser.com',
 'tex.stackexchange.com',
 'travel.stackexchange.com',
 'twitter.com',
 'unix.stackexchange.com',
 'ux.stackexchange.com',
 'video.stackexchange.com',
 'webapps.stackexchange.com',
 'webmasters.stackexchange.com',
 'windowsphone.stackexchange.com',
 'wordpress.stackexchange.com',
 'worldbuilding.stackexchange.com',
 'www.facebook.com',
 'www.g2.com',
 'www.instagram.com',
 'www.w3.org'}
```

NOTE: для парсинга HTML лучше использовать [инструменты, специально для этого предназначенные](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/).

Comment: пока не могу посмотреть, то что я уже опробовал, выдало мне только ```!DOCTYPE```

Comment: Это не является ответом на вопрос, поскольку мне нужно отсеять все ссылки из ```requests.get(url).text```, что также отмечено в вопросе

Comment: @Lcashe, приведите в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных и результат, который вы хотите получить

Comment: резонно, сейчас изменю